# Closed form solution of an improper integral

Tags: integration, complex-integration

The integrals
$$
I_1=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\exp(-\sqrt{x^2 + c})}{\sqrt{x^2 + c}} \, dx,\qquad 
I_2 = \int_0^{+\infty} \sqrt{x^2 + c} \, \exp(-\sqrt{x^2 + c}) \, dx
$$
where $c\in \mathbb{C}$ and $\Re[c] < 0, \Im[c]>0$.
These integrals comes from some electromagnetic Green's function.
They seem to be quite trivial, but I can't seem to find a way to construct closed curves that allow use of e.g. Jordan's lemma.

Comment: These integrals are related to Bessel functions. Indeed


$$ I_1(c) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\exp(-\sqrt{x^2+c})}{\sqrt{x^2+c}}\,dx \stackrel{x\mapsto z\sqrt{c}}{=}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\exp(-\sqrt{c}\sqrt{z^2+1})}{\sqrt{z^2+1}}\,dx $$
equals
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-\sqrt{c}\cosh u\right)\,du. $$

Comment: Indeed, I agree with @JackD'Aurizio. $$I_1 (c)=K_0 \left(\sqrt{c}\right)$$ and $$I_2(c)=cK_0\left(\sqrt{c}\right)+\sqrt{c}K_1\left(\sqrt{c}\right)$$ with $K_\alpha$ being the modified Bessel function of the second kind of order $\alpha$.